# If $X$ is a Markov process, can we find a mild assumption ensuring that $\frac1t\operatorname E_x\left[\int_0^tc(X_s)\:{\rm d}s\right]\to c(x)$?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, operator-theory, markov-chains, semigroups-of-operators

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space with $\{x\}\in\mathcal E$ for all $x\in E$
- $\mathcal E_b:=\{f:E\to\mathbb R\mid f\text{ is bounded and }\mathcal E\text{-measurable}\}$
- $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a Markov semigroup on $(E,\mathcal E)$
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space
- $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$
- $\left(\mathcal F^X_t\right)_{t\ge0}$ denote the filtration generated by $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$
- $\operatorname P_x$ be a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ with $$\operatorname P_x[X_0=x]=1\tag1$$ and $$\operatorname E\left[f(X_{s+t})\mid\mathcal F^X_s\right]=(\kappa_tf)(X_s)\tag2\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in\mathcal E_b\text{ and }s,t\ge0$$
- $c:E\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable

Assume that $X:\Omega\times[0,\infty)\to E$ is $(\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal B([0,\infty)),\mathcal E)$-measurable and hence $$Y_t:=\int_0^tc(X_s)\:{\rm d}s$$ is a well-defined $[0,\infty]$-valued random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ for all $t\ge0$.

> I'm searching for a mild additional assumption, ensuring that $$\frac{\operatorname E_x[Y_t]}t\xrightarrow{t\to0+}c(x)\tag3.$$ For example, I could imagine that we need to assume that
>
> 1. $E$ is a topological space and $\mathcal E=\mathcal B(E)$
> 2. $c$ is locally bounded
> 3. $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ is càdlàg
>
> Would this be enough to conclude?

We may note that $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a contraction semigroup on $\mathcal E_b$. If $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ would be strongly continuous, we could conclude that $$\frac1t\int_0^t\kappa_sf\:{\rm d}s\xrightarrow{t\to0+}f\tag4$$ for all $f\in\mathcal E_b$. However, $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ doesn't need to be strongly continuous and hence we cannot apply this. On the other hand, $(4)$ is clearly stronger than what we need for $(3)$ to hold.

To begin with, we might want to note that $$c_n:=\min(c,n)\in\mathcal E_b\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N.$$

Comment: The simple way is to assume that $X$ is right-continuous, that $c$ is continuous at $x$ and bounded. Then Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem applies after a change of variable $s=tu$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Thank you for your comment. Yes, I know, but unfortunately boundedness of $c$ is a too strong assumption. The only thing I'm willing to admit in that direction is *local* boundedness of $c$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Let $Z:=c\circ X$. After we have shown that, as long as $c$ is bounded, $$\frac1t\operatorname E_x\left[\int_0^tZ_s\:{\rm d}s\right]\xrightarrow{t\to0+}\operatorname E_x[Z_0]\tag5,$$ aren't we able to conclude by replacing $Z$ with $Z^n:=\min(Z,n)$? The monotone convergence theorem should yield $$\operatorname E_x\left[\int_0^tZ^n_s\:{\rm d}s\right]\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\operatorname E_x\left[\int_0^tZ_s\:{\rm d}s\right]\tag6$$ and $$\operatorname E_x[Z^n_0]\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\operatorname E_x[Z_0]\tag7.$$ Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan If not, it would be interesting if we can drop the continuity assumption by approximating $c$ in a suitable way ... Do you think that's possible?

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan I'd still be interested in your opinion.

Comment: @OXbadfood Other possible assumption that may work: $c$ Hölder with exponent $\alpha$ and $E[d(x,X_t)^\alpha] \to 0$ as $t \to 0$ under $P_x$. I do not see how to avoid global assumptions on $c$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, this is just an idea. If you assume that$^1$

1. $E$ is LCCB,
2. $X$ is càdlàg,
3. $X$ is strong Markov, and
4. $X$ is quasi-left continuous,

then for any $t$ the set
$$
    A = \{X_s(\omega) : 0\le s \le t < \infty\}
$$
is almost surely bounded.$^2$ So in that case local boundedness of $c$ would be enough to apply dominated convergence, because you could contain $A$ in a compact set on which $c$ is bounded.

<sub>1: Along with your assumptions, these ensure that $X$ is a Hunt process, but not necessarily a Feller process.</sub>

<sub>2: Proposition I-9.3 in Blumenthal and Getoor's book.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your input. I've checked Blumental and Getoor, but unless I'm missing something the bound for the set $A$ does depend on $\omega$. To be precise, if I understand the claim correctly, they say that for each $t\ge0$, there is a null set $N$ such that $\{X_s(\omega):s\in[0,t]\}$ is bounded for all $\omega\not\in N$. So, the bound should depend on $\omega$ and hence this is not enough to apply the DCT.

Comment: Please see https://mathoverflow.net/q/426699/91890.

Comment: True it doesn't take you all the way there, but I think it could be used to show that $\mathbb P_x(X_s\in U \text{ for all }0\le s < t)\to 1$ as $t\to0$ for all open $U$ containing $x$.

Comment: Don't you think that we need to assume continuity of $c$? Actually, the only thing we need is continuity of $c\circ X$ at $0$, but I don't see any assumption other than continuity of $c$ which would ensure that. Morever, what do you think about the attempt I've described in the comments below the question?

Comment: How would you conclude from $\mathbb P_x(X_s\in U \text{ for all }0\le s < t)\to 1$ for each open neighborhood $U$ of $x$? Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4495504/47771.

Comment: It seems like there is a counterexample: Take $E=\mathbb R$, $\mathcal E=\mathcal B(E)$, $c(x)=x$ and $X_s=s+tY$ for some $V\ge0$ with $\operatorname E_x[Y]=\infty$. If $U$ is an open neighborhood of $x$, there is a $\varepsilon>0$ with $N\subseteq U$ and $$\operatorname P_x[X_s\in U\text{ for all }s\in[0,t)]\ge\operatorname P_x[X_s\in B_\varepsilon(x)\text{ for all }s\in[0,t)]=\operatorname P_x[\|V\|_E<\frac\varepsilon s\text{ for all }s\in[0,t)]\xrightarrow{t\to0+}1.$$ On the other hand, $\operatorname E_x\left[\frac1tY_t\right]=x+\frac t2\operatorname E_x[V]=\infty$.