# What is the significance of Blumenthal and Getoor's result on the boundedness of paths of a standard Markov process?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

In the book *Markov processes and Potential Theory* of Blumenthal and Getoor we can find the following result:

[image]
[image]

I don't understand the significance of this result. If I don't misinterpret the assertion, the claim is that for allmost all $\omega\in\Omega$ and for all $t\in[0,\zeta(\omega))$, the set $\{X_s(\omega):s\in[0,t]\}$ is bounded.

However, it is a basic fact that every function $x:[a,b]\to E_\Delta$ which has left and right limits at every point is bounded. So, it seems like the assertion immediately follows.

It would clearly be a stronger statement if the claim would be that $\{X_s(\omega):s\in[0,\zeta(\omega))\text{ and }\omega\in\Omega\setminus N\}$ is bounded for some null set $N\subseteq\Omega$. But that doesn't seem to be claim and it doesn't seem to be the thing which is shown in the proof (since $n$ in the last paragraph depends on $\omega$).

> What am I missing? It seems like a very basic fact is proven in a complicated way.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple fact, but not quite as simple as you claim. For example, the function
$$
    x: [a,b] \to \mathbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\} : t\mapsto \frac 1 {b-t}
$$
is càdlàg but not bounded.
The rough meaning of the proposition is that if $t\in[0,\infty)$ is strictly less than the first hitting time of $\Delta$ (that is, the first exit time of $E$), then the path of the process up to time $t$ is contained in a compact set. Put another way, the first hitting time of $\Delta$ is equal to $\lim_n T_n$, where the $T_n$ are as in the proof above. This relies on quasi-left continuity (on $[0,\zeta)$), and an example of a process that is not q-lc and doesn't satisfy the result is the [deterministic motion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=tan%28x%25%28pi%2F2%29%29)
$$
    X_t = \tan(t \text{ (mod } \pi/2)), \qquad t\in[0,\infty).
$$
Here the stopping time $T = \lim_n T_n$ is strictly less than the first hitting time of $\Delta$ (which is $\infty$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need to disagree. Your example is not a valid counterexample, since your $x$ is not real-valued.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm missing, but assume that $(E,d)$ is a metric space and $x:[a,b]\to E$ is a function with left and right limits. Assume $x$ is unbounded. Then there is a $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\subseteq[a,b]$ with $d(x(t_0),x(t_n))\ge n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Since $[a,b]$ is sequentially compact, $t_{n_k}\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}t$ for some increasing $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb N$ and $t\in[a,b]$. $(t_{n_{k_l}})_{l\in\mathbb N}$ is monotonic for some increasing $(k_l)_{l\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb N$.

Comment: Assume it is nondecreasing. Then, $d(x(t_{n_{k_l}}),x(t-))\xrightarrow{l\to\infty}0$ and hence $$\infty\xleftarrow{l\to\infty}n_{k_l}\le d(x(t_0),x(t_{n_{k_l}}))\le x(t_0),x(t-))+d(x(t_{n_{k_l}}),x(t-))\xrightarrow{l\to\infty}d(x(t_0),x(t-));$$ which is impossible. So, $x$ is bounded.

Comment: My $x$ is valued in $E_\Delta$, where $E=\mathbb R$ and  $\Delta$ is the infinity point $\pm\infty$ from the one-point compactification of $\mathbb R$. But in any case it is still a counter example if I take $x(t) = 1/(b-t)$ for $a\le t<b$, and $x(b) = 0$.

Comment: Well, it seems like you are right, but what is wrong in my proof above?

Comment: It is not true that $d(x(t_{n_{k_l}}), x(t-)) \to 0$ as $l\to\infty$, because $x(t-) = \infty$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. $x$ is $E$-valued; hence cannot take the value $\infty$. And $d(x(t_{n_{k_l}}), x(t-)) \to 0$ holds by the very definition of $x(t-)$ as being the limit of $x$ under any sequence approach $t$ from the left (which $t_{n_{k_l}}$ does).

Comment: To be clear, $\mathbb R_\Delta$ is not itself the one-point compactification. If it were, then the result would be trivial because $\mathbb R_\Delta$ itself would be a compact set. The point $\Delta$ can actually be any point not in $E$. The toplogy on $E$ is extended by considering $\{\Delta\}$ to be an open set.

So we want to keep $d$ as the Euclidean metric, and define the $x(t-)$ to be equal $\infty$ if and only if it is separated from every other point in $\mathbb R$ by a compact set.

Comment: Please forget your scenario and consider the general case of a metric space $E$ that I've described above. As I wrote, $d(x(t_{n_{k_l}}), x(t-)) \to 0$ then holds by definition. So why do you think my assertion and my proof are wrong?

Comment: Nothing changes in general. $E_\Delta$ is not the compactification of $E$, and $x(t-)$ may equal $\Delta$, in the sense not of $d$ converging to zero but in the sense I defined above.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't follow your argumentation. It doesn't matter which point of $E$ the value $x(t-)$ is equal to. By the very definition of $x(t-)$, it is equal to the limit of $x\left(t_{n_{k_l}}\right)$ as $l\to\infty$. So, there should be no problem with my proof above.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/444853/47771 if you like.

Comment: or the book of Applebaum: https://books.google.com/books?id=q7eDUjdJxIkC&pg=PA118&lpg=PA118&dq=cadlag+function+bounded+applebaum&source=bl&ots=AtfwrwrRHn&sig=ACfU3U19LqWNsvNsx87P6-lKVG2mEJP0sQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLvu6Dm4f5AhUEVPEDHZVKBeoQ6AF6BAgaEAM#v=onepage&q=cadlag%20function%20bounded%20applebaum&f=false. They all claim that a càdlàg function is bounded on compact intervals (but, as I wrote above, it is even true for every function which has left- and right- limits)

Comment: Yes, it is true for any function with compact image. But $E_\Delta$ need not be compact.

Comment: The claim is given for any càdlàg function $[a,b]\to E$, where $E$ is an arbitrary metric space. THe one-point camptification (which is not the topic of this question) is metrizable if $E$ is locally compact and hence the result applies.